# Does Passing Self Through A Protocol Cause Memory Leaks?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having some difficulty wrapping my head around this

Let's say I have a custom view with a protocol to be used by another class (View Controller)

```
protocol MyViewDelegate : AnyObject {
    func parentNeedsToTakeAction(sender: MyView)
}

class MyView : UIView {
  ...
  weak var delegate : MyViewDelegate?
  ....
  func initiateCallBack(){
      delegate?.parentNeedsToTakeAction(self)
  }
}
```

And the view controller conforms to the delegate for this view

I know up to the point before I pass self back up to the VC that the VC holds a strong reference to the view while the view only holds a weak reference to the VC (through the delegate)

But what happens after? Is the ARC for the view now at 2 or still at 1, does the VC hold 1 or 2 strong references to the view?

If in the VC I proceed to take action and then remove the sender (the child view) from it's view does the child view get deallocated from memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A memory leak can only be caused if the recipient of a reference *retains* that reference over a period of time. When you call `delegate?.parentNeedsToTakeAction(self)`, the method `parentNeedsToTakeAction` runs for an incredibly short time and then ends. No reference to `self` is retained over time, so there is no danger of a leak.